# Nesting a second query inside a list of unique column values

Tags: mysql, pdo

Beginner here, be gentle please. I have a table in which one column is book titles and another is their corresponding authors. I'm using PDO to connect to the database and display the results of a query on a webpage. Basically I want each UNIQUE author displayed once, and then a list of each book title that author wrote beneath, like so:

```
Author 1
title1
title2

Author 2
title3
title4
```

Query to get a list of distinct authors:

```
<?php try {

$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT author FROM booktable;"

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

} ?>
```

Foreach loop to display each author:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

     <p><?php echo ($row["author"]); ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

So far so good, this gives me a list of unique authors. For the titles, I was trying to do another foreach loop nested inside the first to display a second query, but I can't figure out how to get only the author the loop is currently on. I tried setting a variable inside the loop like so:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

     <p><?php echo ($row["author"]); ?></p>

     <?php $currentauthor = ($row["author"]); ?>

     <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2) { ?>

          <p><?php echo ($row2["title"]); ?></p>

     <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

And then adding another query in my original TRY (along with a corresponding new connection and fetch statement):

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM booktable WHERE author = '$currentauthor'";)
```

But that returns nothing because the $currentauthor variable doesn't exist outside the foreach loop. So there's my issue. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What's wrong with joins?

Comment: I have no idea what a join is to be honest. I'm very new to this.

Comment: I really think any introductory book or tutorial on MySQL (and MySQL and PHP) would be immensely useful.

Comment: Isn't a join for two or more tables though? I only have one table.

Comment: No. Joins are for joining instances of tables, be they 1, 2, or a 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do what you are attempting with a single, non-joining query. You can use `SELECT * FROM booktable ORDER BY author`, and loop through it's results, only outputting author data when you detect the current record has a different author than the previous one (and for the first record obviously).

A note since you're new: the `*` in `SELECT *` is generally considered bad form for final, deployed queries; I merely used it here as a placeholder since I do not know all the fields you want data from. It is best to specify all the fields you will be using, as it: (1) documents the data used without having to inspect all code that works with the data, (2) makes the query less fragile by not depending on the table definition for column order, (3) makes the query break if a used field is removed from the table, rather than later code that assumes the value will be there (which then has to be tracked back to the query), (4) keeps the amount of data that needs to be collected together and transferred to only what is needed, and (5) more...

Comment: Actually I was just trying something like this and it DID work (basically created an empty variable for the author, wrote to it every loop and checked it against itself), but I couldn't figure out how to paginate the results based upon the author instead of the book count. But that's a whole different question I guess.

Comment: I'm using * in most of my queries because I literally do want all the columns for the project I'm doing. So it would still be better to list the columns I want?

Comment: If this is just a little teach yourself project that you and only you will ever work on, and probably never come back to; that is probably fine. It is more an issue with large systems with multiple devs or long term development when it becomes really important. In an extreme example, imagine you have a "products" table. Starting out on the project it has little more than an id, name, and price; so you select * to get a list of products... later someone a blob field id added for a high res photo for each product; now your text only lists are downloading numerous files they don't actually use.

Comment: Thanks for the help.